# How to properly uninstall AdMob from iOS app

Tags: swift, admob, ios15, xcode13

I have uninstalled the AdMob SDK by commenting out the lines in the Podfile. Then I run pod update. The AdMob SDK and the utilities are removed. However, I get **framework not found FBLPromises** error.

I have use_frameworks! uncommitted in the Podfile.
Even if I comment out use_frameworks! And run pod update I still get the error.

Here's my Podfile.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '15.0'

target 'My Collection' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Auburn Collection
  pod 'Gemini', '~> 1.4'
#  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 8.9'
#  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '~> 7.5'
  pod 'TTSegmentedControl', '~> 0.4.9'
end
```

Two questions:

Do I need to use frameworks for the two remaining pods?

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix the error?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `FBLPromises` is probably part of admob.

Answer (score 1):

I did a search in my app for FBLPromises. It was still in Build Settings > Linking > Other Linked Flags. I had to manually delete it along with other AdMob frameworks. This solved the problem.

It also appears that Gemini uses frameworks so I do need them.